# ipython iptest ImportError( no module named ipython)

Tags: python, windows, ipython, nose

I'm trying to install ipython notebook on my win8 laptop.

I follow the following steps to install ipython.

1. I installed "pip".
2. Then I install the pywin32.
3. Then I used pip to install ipython

   "pip install ipython[all]"

But when I test the ipython using "iptest"
The test can not proceed due to the following error.

> ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named ipython)
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\loader.py", line 420, in loadTestsFromName
>
> addr.filename, addr.module)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 47, in importFromPath
>
> return self.importFromDir(dir_path, fqname)
>
> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose\importer.py", line 79, in importFromDir
>
> fh, filename, desc = find_module(part, path)
>
> ImportError: No module named ipython

The wired thing is the ipython notebook seems working fine, but the iptest can't test properly. It appears to me the the "nose" module cannot find the path of "ipython" module. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you create your virtual environment with `--system-site-packages`.

Try following steps:

1. Exit virtual environment: `deactivate`
2. Switch to superuser: `su root`
3. Install jupyter outside the virtual environment: `sudo pip3 install jupyter`

Then enter your virtual environment and try again.

Comment: Can you explain why? I'm new to venv and ipython. Thanks~

Comment: @Michelle when use [`--system-site-packages`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/#the-system-site-packages-option) option, your virtual environment will inherit packages from system packages. You can see your traceback and see the calling chain is in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` (in Linux) instead of in your virtualenv. And don't use `sudo` when installing packages in virtualenv, otherwise packages will be installed in system path instead of in virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks for your explaination!